# search a string in a file with case insensitive file name

Tags: linux, grep

I want to grep for a string in all the files which have a particular patter in their name and is case-insensitive.

For eg if I have two files ABC.txt and aBc.txt, then I want something like

```
grep -i 'test' *ABC*
```

The above command should look in both the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` and then `grep` on the results of that:

```
find . -iname "*ABC*" -exec grep -i "test" {} \;
```

Note that this will run `grep` once on each file found. If you want to run `grep` once on all the files (in which case you risk running into the command line length limit), you can use a plus at the end:

```
find . -iname "*ABC*" -exec grep -i "test" {} \+
```

You can also use `xargs` to process a really large number of results more efficiently:

```
find . -iname "*ABC*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i test
```

The `-print0` makes `find` output 0-terminated results, and the `-0` makes `xargs` able to deal with this format, which means you don't need to worry about any special characters in the filenames. However, it is not totally portable, since it's a GNU extension.

If you don't have a `find` that supports `-print0` (for example SVR4), you *can* still use `-exec` as above or just

```
find . -iname "*ABC*" | xargs grep -i test
```

But you should be sure your filenames don't have newlines in them, otherwise `xargs` will treat each line of a filename as a new argument.

Comment: I usually run `find . -iname "*ABC*" | xargs grep -i 'test'`. It is much faster when you have many files with names without spaces

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find` to match file and search string that you want with command `grep` which support regular expression, for your question, you should input command like below:

```
find . -name "*ABC*" -exec grep \<test\> {} \;
```